# Have a script simulate a control, keypress sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-controls, greasemonkey, keypress

I've searched and discovered that I can simulate a keypress event using jQuery, but my knowledge about jQuery is poor and I didn't get how exactly.

So I have a Greasemonkey script which manages 2 different webpages in 2 tabs.
I'd like to simulate/auto-execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to the previous tab automatically, this way I could change tabs in Firefox.

The problem is that it's not only a plain keypress, I need to simulate a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> parts too.

I've added this to my script:

```
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

and tried:

```
function testEvents(){
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.which = 9;
$("whatever").trigger(press.ctrlKey + press.shiftKey + press.which);
```

}

without success.

Some links I've seen:
[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events),
[simulate jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js), and http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simulating-keypress-events

Comment: I think taht way they are send to the webpage, and not the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript cannot be used to trigger a default behavior by simulating "shortcut" key events.

Since jQuery is just a different way to write JavaScript code, the restriction also applies.
And, because Greasemonkey scripts are based on JavaScript, without extra functionality besides the `GM_*` methods, it is not possible to write a User script which switches tabs.

Comment: So which `GM_*` method allows this?

Comment: @Tom None. Read the sentence as "gm scripts have no extra functionality besides `GM_*` methods", "so it is not possible to write a user script to switch tabs".

Comment: While is true that javascript cannot use tabs, is not impossible to do that.

Comment: @erm3nda Are you aware of a way to switch tabs without showing a modal dialog in Greasemonkey? If so, post it as an answer, others may be interested in your findings.

Comment: It would be not easy to explain. Lot of things involved for a general answer. If i see a piece of code or the operation's flow i can put an answer.
I need to know why is really need to change tab, because the javascript runs also on a hided tab. So... need more explanation about the problem.